# Combining an 3D Isosurface and Surface Plot in Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am attempting to combine a 3D surface plot as shown [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-surface-plots/) and a 3D isosurface plot as shown [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/3d-isosurface-plots/) in Plotly.

I do not wish to combine them through subplots. The goal is to be able to plot topography with a surface plot and another variable through an isosurface plot, but have them on the same figure.

Is there any way to do this with Plotly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this isn't clearly documented anywhere, the easiest way to do this is simply to provide both plots in the data array provided to `Plotly.newPlot`